# Singleton versus Static: Best practice of web service client declaration

Tags: silverlight-4.0, static, singleton, asmx, webservice-client

I have 2 web services in ASMX type. It is currently declared in App.cs as static.
I am thinking whats the difference between static and singleton instance of web service client declaration.

In static all I need to do is to create this variable

```
static PreferencesWSSoapClient _preferenceWS;
```

and a property

```
public static PreferencesWSSoapClient PreferenceWS
    {
        get 
        {
            if (_preferenceWS == null)
            {
                _preferenceWS = new PreferencesWSSoapClient("PreferencesWSSoap", PrefUri.ToString());
            }
            return _preferenceWS; 
        }

    }
```

In singleton, I need to create a singleton class.

Question is **whats the difference between static and singleton instance of web service client declaration?**

**What is the best practice of web service client declaration?**

Answer (score 0):

It's safer to create a new client object for each request. Not just because a static webclient instance having a lifetime equal to application is an evel itself :) Let me to substantiate my thoughts a bit.

If you use your web service client in Silverlight this means you'll have to use it only in asynchronous mode. It will require using eventhandlers for getting results. And it's be pretty easier to make event attaching mistake if you have only one client instance in the application (I mean here multiple assignments of the same listeners may become quite possible and often issue).